# ERROR ITMS-90022:"Missing required icon file" Xamarin IOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017, xcode9

I am trying to upload app to iTuneConnect and I am keep getting this error

[image]

I have updated the Info.plist as below

```
<key>XSLaunchImageAssets</key>
    <string>Resources/Media.xcassets/LaunchImages.launchimage</string>
    <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
    <string>Resources/Media.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset</string>

    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
          <string>Icon.png</string>
          <string>Icon-60@2x.png</string>
          <string>Icon-72.png</string>
          <string>Icon-72@2x.png</string>
          <string>Icon-76.png</string>
          <string>Icon-76@2x.png</string>
          <string>Icon-83.5@2x.png</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
      <key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
        <dict>
          <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
          <array>
            <string>Icon.png</string>
            <string>Icon-60@2x.png</string>
            <string>Icon-72.png</string>
            <string>Icon-72@2x.png</string>
            <string>Icon-76.png</string>
            <string>Icon-76@2x.png</string>
            <string>Icon-83.5@2x.png</string>
          </array>
        </dict>
      </dict>
    </dict>
  </dict>
```

I also deleted and readded Asset Catalogs but no luck. I am on latest VS2017 Version 15.3.5, Xamarin-4.7.9.45 and Xcode 9.0. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/104004/missing-app-icon-after-updating-to-ios-11-sdk  use only one asset catalog and using png images only.

Comment: delete the `CFBundleIcons` string in info.plist, use Asset Catalogs instead.

Comment: I tried removing  CFBundleIcons from info.plist and added Asset Catalogs its gives same error.

Comment: Try removing UILaunchImages as well, that is what caused it for me after adding an asset catalog